# Less override variable just for one country (language)

Tags: css, less, lessphp

The context of my problem :
I have a website multi-language ( 20 ), I use less css.
All stylesheets are common, except one for every country called to the end.

I have a file com.base.less which has a variable of font. 
Every stylesheet calls this file to use the variables which it contains.

My question, for a country I must change the font, thus to re-declare the variable only for this country. 
How can I proceed?

Because if I re-celare my variable in my file of country, that this being called to the end it isn't written again.

I use lessPhp, and I see ModifyVars but I don't know if it's good method ?
(when I test he doesn't work)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the docs tell you "You can use the ModifyVars() method to customize your CSS if you have variables stored in PHP associative arrays".

Less uses the **last declaration wins** rule for variables, so the last re-declare value of variable at the end of your code will be used everywhere in your code.

> I use lessPhp, and I see ModifyVars but I don't know if it's good
>   method ? (when I test he doesn't work)

Make sure that you call `ModifyVars()` before `getCss()` and call both on the same instance of `Less_Parser`.